# pandas: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files as below, I want to find if an individual performance (in df1) is above/below class average (in df2) using come compare function after finding their values.

```
df1:
 Name    Class    Test1    Test2    Test3
 John       9A       75       83       77
David       9B       65       67       55
Peter       9A       85       90       88
  Tom       9C       74       92       78

df2:
Class    Test1    Test2    Test3
   9A       80       82       84
   9B       84       75       77
   9C       75       78       80
```

Here's my method, feel free to correct/guide me if I'm wrong. I first find the `Class` of an individual  in `df1`, e.g., `John` is `9A`, then return the other columns such as `Test1` or `Test2` in `df2` based on `9A`

```
target_class = df1.loc[df1['Name'] == 'John', 'Class']
print(target_class)
>>>>9A
Test1_avg = df2.loc[df2['Class'] == target_class, 'Test1']
# ideally it should return 80
```

And I got this `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Or simply, how would you compare John's Test1 in df1 vs Class 9A's Test1 in df2? Is there any easier method than mine? Thanks for your help!

**Update**: I'll then use a compare function like this to return a score if it fulfills the criteria

```
def comparison(a, b):
    return 2 if a > b else 1 if a == b else -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way via `pandas.merge`.

```
# rename df2 columns
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Test'+str(x): 'AvgTest'+str(x) for x in range(1, 4)})

# left merge df1 on df2
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Class'])

# calculate comparison results
comparison = pd.DataFrame(res.loc[:, res.columns.str.startswith('Test')].values  >= \
                          res.loc[:, res.columns.str.startswith('AvgTest')].values,
                          columns=['Comp'+str(x) for x in range(1, 4)])

# join results to dataframe
res = res.join(comparison)

print(res)

#     Name Class  Test1  Test2  Test3  AvgTest1  AvgTest2  AvgTest3  Comp1  \
# 0   John    9A     75     83     77        80        82        84  False   
# 1  David    9B     65     67     55        84        75        77  False   
# 2  Peter    9A     85     90     88        80        82        84   True   
# 3    Tom    9C     74     92     78        75        78        80  False   

#    Comp2  Comp3  
# 0   True  False  
# 1  False  False  
# 2   True   True  
# 3   True  False
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about merging 2 dfs into 1. Just a quick question, what if I want to the compare function to return a number instead of boolean, say if Test1>AvgTest1, then return a number/int like 2, if Test1=AvgTest1, return 1, if Test1<AvgTest1, return -1? What would you do? I just updated my answer, but how do I implement your `loc` to it? Thanks.